# Including external tikzpicture with preamble

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I am using the standalone package which is awesome but I have a problem: I'd like to have a tikzpicture in an external file but with custom colors or something but when I include it in the main file with `\includestandalone`, the compilation fails as the main file doesn't know the colors defined in the external file.

For example:

```
% pic.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,1.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\includestandalone{pic}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work because the main file hasn't the colors nor the tikzlibrary imported in `pic.tex`.

How can I make the main file import the preamble of `pic.tex`? Also it would be great that colors and other defined in the standalone file remains local while importing in the main file (in this case I don't want the color `myBlue` to be accessible in the rest of the main file).

Comment: You can include color definition inside document body and make it even more local with `{}`. Something like: `\begin{document}{\definecolor{...}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}`

Answer (score 1):

For me this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{pic.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,1.0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [myBlue] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\includestandalone{pic}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility if you want to use external files if to define a .tex file only with `tikzpicture`, defining commands such as `\definecolor` inside the environment, and then calling it in the main file through the command `input`.

You may test the command `\myBlue` in the main file to verify it is not defined in it.

Personally, I like to define TikZ pictures on a external file and edit them in TikZEdt. It lets me reuse them anywhere else and also make it simple to organize them. I also use `adjustbox` to define the figure size, but that's another subject.

pic.tex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,1.0}
\draw [myBlue] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\input{pic}
%\myBlue{A} % Undefined controle sequence
\end{document}
```